# Unable to send a GET request containing "." query parameter using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I created an API Gateway which contains multiple query parameters.

When I try to invoke its URL on Postman it works very well:

```
'https://xxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/stage/getfile/test.csv/.'
```

But, when I simulate the same request on Lambda, I get a Missing Authentication Token error.

```
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url= 'https://xxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/stage/getfile/test.csv/.'
r=requests.request("GET",url,headers=headers)
r.text
'{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}'
```

Replacing the dot `"."` by another character in the URL makes the error disappear but I need to send a dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No solution is possible for this kind of problem. I had to replace `"."` with `dot` and manage it with my code.